# My java class validation is not working why?

Tags: java, validation

If the quantity is not positive it should be set to 0.
If the price per item is not positive it should be set to 0.0.
Hwever when I enter a negative number it keeps setting my variable negative and not Zero.

This is my class package com.company;

```
/**
 * Created by juliodiaz on 5/7/16.
 */
public class Invoice {

    private String partNumber;
    private String partDescription;
    private int partQuantity;
    private double partPrice;

    public Invoice(String partNumber, String partDescription, int partQuantity, double partPrice) {
        this.partNumber = partNumber;
        this.partDescription = partDescription;
        this.partQuantity = partQuantity;
        this.partPrice = partPrice;
    }

    public String getPartNumber() {
        return partNumber;
    }

    public void setPartNumber(String partNumber) {
        this.partNumber = partNumber;
    }

    public String getPartDescription() {
        return partDescription;
    }

    public void setPartDescription(String partDescription) {
        this.partDescription = partDescription;
    }

    public int getPartQuantity() {
        return partQuantity;
    }

    public void setPartQuantity(int partQuantity) {
        this.partQuantity = partQuantity;
    }

    public double getPartPrice() {
        return partPrice;
    }

    public void setPartPrice(double partPrice) {
        this.partPrice = partPrice;
    }

    public double invoiceAmountMethod(double partPrice, int partQuantity) {
        if (partQuantity < 0 || partPrice < 0.0) {
            this.partQuantity = 0;
            return partPrice * partQuantity;
        }
        else
            return partPrice * partQuantity;
    }
}

//Main method
package com.company;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // write your code here

        Invoice myTruck = new Invoice("A101", "Wheels", -2, 100.00);

        System.out.println(myTruck.getPartDescription());
        System.out.println(myTruck.getPartNumber());
        System.out.println(myTruck.getPartQuantity());
        System.out.println(myTruck.getPartPrice());

        double price = myTruck.getPartPrice();
        int quantity = myTruck.getPartQuantity();

        System.out.println("The total cost is " + myTruck.invoiceAmountMethod(price, quantity));

    }
}
```

**OUTPUT**

```
Wheels
A101
-2
100.0
The total cost is -200.0
```

Comment: Have you put in breakpoints in your method?

Answer (score 1):

You're assigning:

```
this.partQuantity = 0;
```

but you return:

```
return partPrice * partQuantity;
```

(the parameters that were passed to the method).

you can fix it by returning:

```
return this.partPrice * this.partQuantity;
```

and you really shouldn't pass any parameters to this method.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you need.

```
public double invoiceAmountMethod(double partPrice, int partQuantity) {

  return (partQuantity < 0 || partPrice < 0.0)?0.0:partPrice * partQuantity;         

}
```